# Building a simple quiz in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JavaScript and I am trying to write the function solution that will return a integer score verifying how many check-boxes selected by the user are correct. The function **should_be_checked(question_index, choice_index)** is already defined which returns true if the answer is correct or else returns false. I want to use the function should_be_checked inside my solution function to evaluate the score. How do I get the input values in an array from the HTML form and then generate the score using the array values against the correct values from the should_be_checked function.
For example: 
If i do should_be_checked(2, 2) it will return true as it is the right answer.
question_index and choice_index are the values passed as argument to should_be_checked function. The solution() function will be called on a button click once the user selects the check-boxes.

```js
function solution() {
  var score = 0;
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(checkbox => {
      let args = checkbox.attr("id").split("-"); // Split at the dashes to get an array containing ["choice", "1", "2"]
      args.shift() // Remove the first element that says "choice"
      if (checkbox.prop("checked") !== should_be_checked(...args)) {
        score = score + 1; // Increment the score
      });
    return score;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="question-1">
    <legend>Easy question</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice-1-1" checked>Incorrect answer</input>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="question-2">
    <legend>Another sample question</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice-2-1">Sample incorrect answer</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice-2-2" checked="checked">Sample correct answer</input>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or something like that?

Comment: I don't see any reference to a `should_be_checked` function in the code provided here -- just an empty `solution` function.

Comment: jQuery is supported and I can use it.

Comment: What is your should_be_checked function and how do you use it?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah right, I am not sure how do I use it in my function. I am a newbie to JavaScript.

Comment: For example: should_be_checked(2,2) will return true. So i can pass the  question_index, choice_index to the function and it returns true or false based on the choice

Comment: Can you put your `should_be_checked` function inside your question on here on comments?

Comment: Sure, but how are you calling `solution`? On a button click? On submission of the form? The context of a function call is very important in JavaScript. Please [edit] your question to add your comments to the question so that it is more understandable.

Comment: how can you only have an incorrect checkbox for question 1?

Comment: @DCR It is just an example.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the function solution will be called on a button click once the user selects the checkboxes

Comment: @DCR it means it is supposed to be unchecked, these are checkboxes not radio buttons

Comment: You should be using `radio` options. That way the user can only select one option.

Comment: @CoryKleiser Yeah I can. I just wanted to understand how to loop over the input and dump it into an array so that I can validate it using the should_be_checked boolean function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loop over each checkbox you can check if they should be checked using your function

```
let allQuestionsCorrect = true;
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(checkbox => {
  let args = checkbox.attr("id").split("-"); // Split at the dashes to get an array containing ["choice", "1", "2"]
  args.shift() // Remove the first element that says "choice"
  if(checkbox.prop("checked") !== should_be_checked(...args)) {
    allQuestionsCorrect = false; // If it shouldn't be checked and it is or should be checked and it isn't, the questions are not all correct
  }
});
return allQuestionsCorrect
```

Then if their checked property isn't what it should be return false

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i wanted to do, I just was not able to loop over the input check boxes as I am a newbie to JavaScript and it's syntax.

Comment: @Dookoto_Sea This is a nice jquery feature, you can loop over things the same way you use CSS selectors. `input[type=checkbox]` in css will apply a style to all checkboxes, jquery will return a list of all the checkboxes

Comment: Does the (...args) pass the arguments as 1,2? I thought args is an array here

Comment: @Dookoto_Sea Yes, in javascript you can use ... infront of an array in arguments to pass them as seperate arguments. This would be the same as `should_be_checked(args[0], args[1])`

Comment: Okay, this solves my problem and helps me to understand how things work here.